# Multiline Pattern search using python

Tags: python, regex

```
 s="""04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 82
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: Donald
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 83
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): Not doing anything
    04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: Mickey
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 84
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
    04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: Donald
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 83
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
    04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 82
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS"""

    exepat= re.compile(".*Sending request.*?Donald.*?TO BE SENT IS",re.DOTALL)

    reout = exepat.findall(s)

    print reout[0]

Expected Output:
    04-09 11:11:57.879 D/PTT [STACK]( 1653): *********Sending request
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: Donald
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 83
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
    04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
```

I need a pattern to extract requests which have "Donald" in between "Sending request" and "MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS".In the above example two requests contains "Donald".So reout list should have 2 items.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) instead.

`re.MULTILINE` is needed to alter the behaviour of the `^` and `$` start-of-line and end-of-line anchors, `re.DOTALL` makes `.` match newlines too.

> **`re.M`**
>   **`re.MULTILINE`**
>   When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at
>   the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line
>   (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'`
>   matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line
>   (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at
>   the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and
>   immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.
>
> **`re.S`**
>   **`re.DOTALL`**
>   Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a newline.

With `re.DOTALL`, I get:

```
>>> exepat= re.compile(r"Sending request.*TO BE SENT IS", re.DOTALL)
>>> reout = exepat.search(s)
>>> print reout
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a729370>
>>> print reout.group()
Sending request
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd 
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 82
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): 
04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS
```

If you have *multiple* such messages, you need to use a non-greedy `*?` match:

```
exepat = re.compile(r"Sending request.*?TO BE SENT IS", re.DOTALL)
```

Note the question mark; it instructs the multiplier to match the *smallest* number of characters that satisfy the pattern, rather than the most.

Using `.findall()` we then find 3 matches rather than 1 in your updated example:

```
>>> exepat = re.compile(r"Sending request.*?TO BE SENT IS", re.DOTALL)
>>> exepat.findall(s)
['Sending request\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 82\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS', 'Sending request\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 83\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS', 'Sending request\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): *********\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): S: abcd \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): l: jockey\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): k: sucess\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): j: 84\n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): \n04-09 11:11:57.879 [STACK]( 1653): MESSAGE TO BE SENT IS']
>>> len(exepat.findall(s))
3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: My Problem is more complex than what i have explained earlier.I am looking for the blocks between "Sending request" and  "TO BE SENT IS".In the above string it occurs 3 times.So my reout should list 3 items.I Tried "re.findall" and "re.finditer" methods.Output is not as expected.Please help me in this regard